# How to adjust the label position in an Indexed X-axis on Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I am creating a chart in WinForms in C# and the X-axis is **indexed**.

I have 10000 points in the chart series

For some reason, the X-axis labels are labeled From 1 to 10001. Which means when I set the X-value (time) for any point, it does not get displayed for the 10001th label.

I tried setting the following parameters, none of which helped

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.IntervalOffset = -1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalOffset = -1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
```

None of this did anything to help, my chart labels are still reading from 1 to 10001, and no matter how much I zoom in (with added zoom controls) the labels still read on every interval ending with 1. Like 1001, 2001, 3001, .. etc.

How can I change this to read from 0 to 10000? And only show lines and labels on intervals ending with 0

Thanks

EDIT:

The minimum and the maximum were already set, in the screenshot you see below, all the X values are correctly indexed, but for some reason the chart display value 10001

And I do not wish to set the value to the Maximum to 10000 in this case, it will prevent the label from showing up but it will also prevent the ability to scroll the axis past the last measurement.

[image: 10001]

Comment: You need to post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The problem depends on the settings which you applied on the chart and the way you add data to the chart.

Comment: AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1